# Modify the Default Windows Form Objects

Tags: .net, winforms, progress-bar

I'm trying to write a component to replace the existing progress bar in windows.  Is their some way to modify it for all applications?  I'd like to add some functionality to it without expecting everyone to add my modified control to their application.

Is their some way of doing this, preferably with .NET.  It sounds unlikely that it's possible from my angle, but I'd still like to know if it was possible just in general.  I know it'd have to modify some deep stuff to change it.

Now, I'm not being way over ambitious here, just the default windows progress bar control.  Not every uniquely made progress bar concoction out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean modifying control in your OWN .NET application, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx

If you mean modifying Windows itself, it gets tricky. But it's been done:

[image: look here]

http://www.uxstyle.com/

Use a theming option.